# Wait for critical sections to complete in a graceful node.js shutdown

Tags: node.js

I want to update my node application on production, but users are using it for things like credit card transactions.

I run `supervisor`, but I would like to wait until all critical sections (like saving data or sending important information) are complete before it restarts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [up](https://github.com/learnboost/up) by LearnBoost.

> Zero-downtime reloads built on top of the distribute load balancer.

Read more from here:

http://www.devthought.com/2012/01/29/staying-up-with-node-js/

Another one is [ncluster](https://github.com/benmmurphy/ncluster).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a programmed dowtime seems the most straightforward thing to do, just notify the users and stop critical transactions a few minutes before the downtime, always choose the right time to go offline and be sure to be only a small timeframe away from your users.

You could also delegate to more applications the various sections of your app, for example process payments in a separate process you can message with a queue.

This clearly depends on your needs, by te way be sure to disclose a programmed downtime to your users, they will be happy to come back later.